# c++ enum parameter gives identifier error

Tags: c++, enums

So, I have a class named "Player", within the header file I have this:

```
class Player
{
public:
    void move(Player::Direction direction);

private:
    enum Direction { LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN };
};
```

And within the cpp file I have this:

```
void Player::move(Player::Direction direction)
{

}
```

Now my problem is, intellisense says there is no such member as direction withint the class in the header, but in the cpp file it says it's valid. When compiling I get the error: "error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Direction'"

Comment: Does your code compile though? _Intellisense_ isn't reliable until the indexer got through.

Comment: Just move the enum declaration above the function declaration. This is c++ damn it! (not angry)

Comment: I just tested this, works flawlessly if you move the Enum on top of the class.

Comment: If move is public, then the enum should also be public so calling code can use it.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule in C++ is that a declaration of a thing must be seen first before said thing can be used.

Swap the declarations. (Also, the `Player::` is redundant.)

```
class Player
{
private:
    enum Direction { LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN };

public:
    void move(Player::Direction direction);    
};
```